# Is there a library or API for interacting with WebSockets in Mathematica?

Tags: web-access, networking

I'm trying to build a Mathematica model that can retrieve and send data to a service that uses a WebSocket protocol. Is there a library or set of APIs for MMA that interace to WebSockets?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

[Network Programming Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NetworkProgramming.html)

[Web Operations Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WebOperations.html)